# snowflake stored procedure Role

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What is that Role in Snowflake that just provides an ability to get the DDL of the Stored Procedure, or perform a describe procedure? Could not find this in any documents.
Note: This is not about using snowflake.account_usage, rather using information schema or using SHOW/DESCRIBE command.

Answer (score 0):

Only privileges for procedure are usage and owner. Please refer -
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#privileges-on-stored-procedures

Comment: Perhaps post more details of what you are trying to do and what error you get.

Comment: I am trying to execute get_ddl('procedure','name') or describe procedure procedure_name with access errors. what grants do I need on the procedure, I do not want an usage permission on the procedure.

Comment: What is the error you are getting, also where does the procedure resides - is it in a different database/user? If its in same account but different database, I hope you are using filly qualified name for the procedure i.e. including owner database and username.